# update column without auto timestamp update

Tags: mysql, innodb

Hello everyone I have got a product stock table with a time-stamp column so the so any updated to that row will update the time stamp ,I'm happy with this setting but sometimes I want to update the row without updating the time stamp,**so how to write mysql statement  that update a specific column without updating the lastUpdate column ?**

this my statement:
`update productsStock set productName="HP PRINTER 20000" where product_reference="001";`

productsStock table description

`describe productsStock;`

`+--------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field              | Type                  | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| productID          | int(10)               | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| product_reference  | varchar(255)          | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
| productName        | varchar(255)          | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                             |
| brand              | varchar(45)           | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| model              | varchar(100)          | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
| productDescription | varchar(255)          | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| physicalStock      | int(10) unsigned      | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
| price              | decimal(7,2) unsigned | YES  |     | 0.00              |                             |
| location           | varchar(45)           | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| lowStockAlert      | int(10) unsigned      | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
| lastUpdateBy       | varchar(45)           | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| lastUpdate         | timestamp             | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+--------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do your update, set the lastUpdate column equal to itself, that way it won't default in the current timestamp:

```
 update productsStock set productName="HP PRINTER 20000", lastUpdate = lastUpdate where product_reference="001";
```